# Gain access to cameras behind CGNAT

Tags: openvpn, ip-camera

Problem: How to gain access to 2 IP cameras behind CGNAT cellular modem/router

Setup:
Web facing VPS running ubuntu 16.04 with openvpn (server) running on it.

Digi Transport wr31 Modem/Router behind CGNAT Utilizing Neo/Aeris Sim
IFS 4 port Hardened Switch
Raspberry pi running rasbian with (Client) openvpn
2 Interlogix cameras

Various Laptops, tablets and phones on various networks wanting to connect/view Cameras

I can connect into the pi via ssh and vnc, i can use the pi to connect to the cameras, however the pi can not display the video from these cameras(needs special plugin that the pi cant run)

I know there is a way to make it so that i can route to the cameras, however i am unsure how to do this. I would think routing with the server would be the ideal way of doing it, but from what i have seen the camera network and the user network have to have different subnets as well as each device has to be accounted for which i simply can not do. Id be open to using other forms of vpn or even some other form of fancy routing that i am unaware of (ps i am very new to the whole networking thing)

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can try making a pfsense box. Something has to do the routing between the separate subnets. You can avoid a complicated setup for this if you put three nics in the pf box. One for the wan connection, and one for each subnet. Pfsense can also run openvpn. If you have a VLAN capable switch you can do "routing on a stick" and trunk your vlans back to a single nic on the pfsense box, but is a little harder to get going initially. Basically it sounds like you need a router that is also running openvpn, opensense is a fork of pfsense, that would also work.

Comment: The switch is fully capable of doing vlans, the router is capable of doing the vpn among other things. It has 2 Lan side nics,  what vlans are you suggesting I route between? I have tried setting the cameras in the same subnet as the vpn, and it seems to deny access to that connection, maybe because it's not routeable.. Like I said I know very little about this.

Comment: Is the router also capable of vlans? The idea here is your going to use it to route your vlans, so it must be able to read VLAN tags, and be able to create virtual interfaces. You have to create at least three vlans then assign two to the subnets you already have. One would be for the actual wan connection. The router will be used to set up rules like vlan1 can pass through to VLAN 2 for the cameras. Or VPN users can pass through the virtual address pool to vlan1 to access the cameras. Post your router model number. if you don't know if it's VLAN capable I'll look it up for you

Comment: I believe it is. The settings in the thing are overwhelming to say the least.  So you're saying drop the vpn client file onto the router, then set up 3 vlans. One for the vpn, one for the cameras, and one for the Wan. The vpn and cameras can route to each other and the cameras can route to the Wan?

Comment: The VPN usually is it's own subnet, which is routed internally by the router or VPN device. You probably want openvpn running on the router. It will make this less complicated. I'm just going off of what you posted, if it's possible to have everything on one single lan it would make it alot easier. I'm posting from my phone, but I could draw you a basic design when I get back if you want. It really depends on what you need, VLAN separated networks give you excellent control of traffic, including quality of service per VLAN. It's a better choice.

Comment: That would be amazing! If I set up the vpn as a client on the router that would make everything behind it visable to the vpn? (client to client is enabled)

Comment: Depending on the router, hypothetically it should make the route available to the subnets connected to it. It also depends on how your VPN server is physically set up on your network. I'll make you a diagram when I get back.

Comment: Digging more using different keywords It looks like the vpn can assign the cameras an routed ip address in the openvpn subnet with some modifications to the configuration.